# How to solve $\dfrac{7x}{8}+4-\dfrac{2x}{3}=4x-3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

$$\frac{7x}{8}+4-\frac{2x}{3}=4x-3$$

I do not understand how to simplify this. Could anyone here help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{7x}{8}+4-\frac{2x}{3}=4x-3$$

Multiply by the equation by 8 to get rid of the first fraction:

$${7x}+32-\frac{16x}{3}=32x-24$$

Similarly multiply by 3 to get rid of the second fraction:

$${21x}+96-{16x}=96x-72$$

Now you can re-arrange and solve for x.

Collect like terms on both sides:

$$({21x}-{16x}) + 96 =96x-72$$

$$({5x}) + 96 =96x-72$$

Get all terms with `x` on the left side and all other terms on the right side

$${5x} - 96x = -96-72$$

Simplify:

$$-91x = -168$$

**NOTE:**

I did the multiplication in 2 steps to show you "baby steps" but you could do it in a single step by finding the Lowest Common Multiple (LCM) of 8 and 3. which gives you 24.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply R.H.S and L.H.S by $24$ to get rid of fractions and calculate $x$

Comment: how do I come up with the number 24- where does 24 come from

Comment: L.C.M of 8 and 3, the no.s in the denominator which are making it hard to solve. Get it?

Comment: I have the answer but I dont understand the process when i get to x= 168/-91 I get confused

Comment: where are u getting confused you wanted to get rid of the denominators so you multiplied the equation with a no. that is divisible by both, in this case 24.